# SyntaxError on spread operator, while using babel env preset

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to "modernize" [mern.io starter bolerplate](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter) by replacing babel `es2015` and `stage-0` presets with `env`. However, it seems that `env` preset does not recognize the following snippet in [`client/modules/Intl/IntlReducer.js:9`](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/b249417c5b711fb22e9218157a56f1dd17e0f3ef/client/modules/Intl/IntlReducer.js#L9):

```
import { enabledLanguages, localizationData } from '../../../Intl/setup';
import { SWITCH_LANGUAGE } from './IntlActions';

const initLocale = global.navigator && global.navigator.language || 'en';

const initialState = {
  locale: initLocale,
  enabledLanguages,
  ...(localizationData[initLocale] || {}),
// ^ 
// SyntaxError: client/modules/Intl/IntlReducer.js: Unexpected token
};


const IntlReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SWITCH_LANGUAGE: {
      const { type, ...actionWithoutType } = action; // eslint-disable-line
      return { ...state, ...actionWithoutType };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default IntlReducer;
```

`localizationData` object is populated in [`Intl/setup.js:56`](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/blob/b249417c5b711fb22e9218157a56f1dd17e0f3ef/Intl/setup.js#L56)

This spread operator seems quite normal to me, I cannot spot the syntax error.
Also it seems that other code preceding to this file, is being transpiled just fine, so I guess env preset is applied correctly.

What may be the reason of this failure? Was this particular flavor of spread operator not accepted from stage-0 into current version of ES? How can I investigate this issue further?

Full error message (project root path stripped):

```
node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: client/modules/Intl/IntlReducer.js: Unexpected token (9:2)
   7 |   locale: initLocale,
   8 |   enabledLanguages,
>  9 |   ...localizationData[initLocale]
     |   ^
  10 | };
  11 | 
  12 | const IntlReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseIdentifier (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4332:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parsePropertyName (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4156:96)
    at Parser.parsePropertyName (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:6229:23)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseObj (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4045:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3719:19)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:7238:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:6474:20)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVar (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2340:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVarStatement (node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2169:8)
```

Comment: Object spread is not in the specification yet, it's in stage 3 AFAIK.

Comment: @elclanrs I see. Is there a good trusted source where one can learn about what proposed features are in which state currently? What would be the correct "future-proof" way for me to fix the error? To add "stage-3" preset or to add "transform-object-rest-spread" plugin, or something else?

Comment: You can track it in this repo https://github.com/tc39/proposals. In your case you'd need to add the extra babel transform.

Comment: @Drop use [babel site](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins#presets) to see what you get out of the presets.

Comment: I checked both resources, thank you guys. The issue is solved by adding `"transform-object-rest-spread"` into `plugins` in `.babelrc` and installing `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` package. @elclanrs Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: @FelixKling Wow! Should we call it "The thing that don't have name in the spec" then? To shorten a bit I propose to name it simply "Resty McSpreadface" :)

Comment: I had this interesting conversion regarding my naming suggestion: https://mobile.twitter.com/fkling42/status/880482008421474305 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object spread is not in the specification yet, it is currently in stage 3, which means that the `env` preset won't provide this feature.

If you want to use this feature with Babel, you will need to add the [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread) transform.

You can check the status of the ES proposals in this repo https://github.com/tc39/proposals

Comment: Thank you. Just updated Node to 8.12.0 and it's working fine now! @elclanrs